# paypal - Reccuring payment - Trial period

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment

I set up a recurring payment at my application.

I have defined these parameters in my application:

```
'TRIALBILLINGPERIOD' = 'Month'
'TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY' =  1,
'TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES' =  1 
'PROFILESTARTDATE' = "date (DATE_ATOM)";
```

The problem exists within the result provided by Paypal, more precisely at the `"Next payment due"` value. I launched the recurrent payment on 19 January, will the `"Next payment due"` be 19 January or after one month?